# Print non-overlapping date blocks in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-loops

I have the following table:

```
ID START_DATE    END_DATE           
 1 01.06.2015  20.06.2015 
 2 05.06.2015  25.06.2015 
 3 03.06.2015  10.06.2015 
 4 07.06.2015  23.06.2015 
 5 21.06.2015  30.06.2015 
 6 02.06.2015  10.06.2015 
 7 05.06.2015  15.06.2015 
 8 05.06.2015  08.06.2015 
 9 16.06.2015  20.06.2015
```

There are overlapping timelines in the table. For eg, `03/06/2015-10/06/2015` resides between `1/06/2015-20/06/2015`. Infact the non-overlapping timelines are `1/06/2015`,`05/06/2015` and `21/06/2015`. I have to retrieve these values. I am aware of the fact that I have to use nested loop to compare a particular date with every other date. What I have done is:

```
DECLARE
 min_sd DATE;
 max_ed DATE;
 sd DATE;
 ed DATE;
 i INT:=1;
 j INT:=1;

PROCEDURE date_block
IS

BEGIN

  WHILE i<=9 loop
  SELECT start_date,end_date INTO min_sd,max_ed FROM sd_ed WHERE id=i;

    WHILE j<=9 loop
     SELECT start_date,end_date INTO sd,ed FROM sd_ed WHERE id=j;

      IF min_sd<=sd AND max_ed>=ed THEN
        j:=j+1;

      ELSE
        Dbms_Output.put_line(sd||' - '||ed);
        j:=j+1;

       END IF;
      i:=i+1;

    END LOOP;

  END loop;
END;

BEGIN
  date_block();
END;
```

The output I am getting is:

```
05-JUN-15 - 25-JUN-15
07-JUN-15 - 23-JUN-15
21-JUN-15 - 30-JUN-15
```

I think the dates are not being compared to the dates present above them in the table.Can anyone help? I am using oracle.

Using SQL only,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM  sd_ed
        ORDER BY id) a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   sd_ed_test b
               WHERE  b.start_date <= a.start_date
               AND    b.end_date   >= a.end_date
               AND    b.id         <  a.id
               );
```

Comment: Never do in `PL/SQL` when  you could do it in pure `SQL`.

Comment: As far as I know, PL/SQL has a lot of advantages over SQL.

Comment: SQL directly interacts with database, PL/SQL is a different engine. Read context switching. Post the create and insert statements, use to_date for the dates in the insert statements. See how to provide a [test case](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Test_case). I will provide the required SQL.

Comment: So what's the question now? If you have managed to do it in SQL, pretty good, You did it yourself.

Comment: Now I have to combine the overlapping dates to create a continuous interval. For eg, 1/06/2015-20/06/2015 should be combined with 5/06/2105-25/06/2015 to produce 1/06/2015-25/06/2015.

Comment: Use MIN and MAX. But if you start combining the rows, finally you will end up with a single row. So, you need to explain the rule.

Comment: There don't appear to be any non overlapping date ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure SQL solution:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8eac7/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table sd_ed as with sd_ed(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) as (
select 1, to_date('01.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('20.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('05.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('25.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 3, to_date('03.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('10.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 4, to_date('07.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('23.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 5, to_date('21.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('30.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 6, to_date('02.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('10.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 7, to_date('05.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('15.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 8, to_date('05.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('08.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 9, to_date('16.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('20.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
) select * from sd_ed;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with super as(
  -- Select the super ranges.  All other ranges are
  -- completely contained in at least one super range
  select id, start_date, end_date
    from sd_ed a
   where not exists (select 1
                       from sd_ed b
                      where a.id <> b.id
                        and b.start_date <= a.start_date
                        and a.end_date <= b.end_date)
), hier(id, start_date, end_date) as (
-- Select all record with a start date not between
-- any other records start and end dates
select id, start_date, end_date from super
 where not exists(select 1 from super d1
                   where d1.id <> super.id
                     and super.start_date between d1.start_date and d1.end_date
                     and super.start_date <> d1.start_date)
-- Recursively select records that overlap the current range
-- but with end dates after the end date of the current range
union all
select sd_ed.id
     , prev.start_date
     , greatest(sd_ed.end_date, prev.end_date)
  from hier prev
  join sd_ed
    on sd_ed.id <> prev.id
   and sd_ed.start_date <= prev.end_date
   and prev.end_date < sd_ed.end_Date
)
-- Get the max end_date for each start date.
-- Start Dates are already minimum for any range.
select start_date, max(end_Date) end_date
  from hier
 group by start_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8eac7/1/0)**:

```
|             START_DATE |               END_DATE |
|------------------------|------------------------|
| June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | June, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
```

For this data set identifying the super ranges isn't really needed since the hierarchical query will handle it just fine, but for larger data sets this initial pruning will reduced the amount of work that needs to be done by the hierarchical query.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained clearly how you are identifying the non-overlapping date ranges. Here is a solution that lists all the days between each range then discards all duplicate days (leaving only those days which only appear in a single range) then groups them into blocks of contiguous days.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd25f/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table sd_ed (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) as
select 1, to_date('01.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('20.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('05.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('25.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 3, to_date('03.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('10.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 4, to_date('07.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('23.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 5, to_date('21.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('30.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 6, to_date('02.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('10.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 7, to_date('05.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('15.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 8, to_date('05.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('08.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
select 9, to_date('16.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('20.06.2015','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH days AS (
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS Day
  FROM   sd_ed s,
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT s.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY s.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 <= s.END_DATE
             )
             AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
           )
         ) d
  GROUP BY COLUMN_VALUE
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
),
Group_Changes AS (
  SELECT Day,
         CASE WHEN LAG( Day ) OVER ( ORDER BY Day ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY = Day THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Change_Group
  FROM   Days
),
Groups AS (
  SELECT Day,
         SUM( Change_Group ) OVER ( ORDER BY Day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS group_id
  FROM   Group_Changes
)
SELECT MIN( Day ) AS start_date,
       MAX( Day ) AS end_date
FROM   Groups
GROUP BY Group_Id
ORDER BY 1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd25f/13/0)**:

```
|             START_DATE |               END_DATE |
|------------------------|------------------------|
| June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | June, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 26 2015 00:00:00 | June, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
```

However, if you only want a list of the date ranges in the table then you can do (the same as above without the `HAVING COUNT(1) = 1` line):

**Query 2**:

```
WITH days AS (
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS Day
  FROM   sd_ed s,
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT s.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY s.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 <= s.END_DATE
             )
             AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
           )
         ) d
  GROUP BY COLUMN_VALUE
),
Group_Changes AS (
  SELECT Day,
         CASE WHEN LAG( Day ) OVER ( ORDER BY Day ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY = Day THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Change_Group
  FROM   Days
),
Groups AS (
  SELECT Day,
         SUM( Change_Group ) OVER ( ORDER BY Day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS group_id
  FROM   Group_Changes
)
SELECT MIN( Day ) AS start_date,
       MAX( Day ) AS end_date
FROM   Groups
GROUP BY Group_Id
ORDER BY 1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd25f/13/1)**:

```
|             START_DATE |               END_DATE |
|------------------------|------------------------|
| June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | June, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
```